# What does "MongoError: Error: corrupt bson message" mean?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm suddenly running into this issue with MongoDB.  We are running a NodeJS app with npm mongoose (v4.1.3), npm mongodb (v2.0.42), and MongoDB (v3.0.10). We are running a replica set with a primary and one secondary.  This coincides with a recently deployed new version of our app in production, but we haven't changed versions of MongoDB or mongoose recently, so I'm not sure why this is suddenly happening.

I can't find any useful information on what causes this error, or what it means. After the error occurs, our mongoose connection locks up and all interaction with the database becomes a black hole of unresponsiveness.  Rebooting the app is the only way to restore database connectivity.

I'm interested in what this error message means and how to prevent it from happening.

The error has happened while interacting with 2 different collections, with 2 different queries.  The queries are very basic.

```
MongoError: Error: corrupt bson message
at .messageHandler (../node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:245:29)
at Socket.<anonymous> (../node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:181:18)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:177:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:135:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:542:20)
```

Comment: can you show your `2 different connections with 2 different queries` code?